# asp.net core cookies issue

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies

I have two asp.net core applications running on the same server, when one application set value into cookies it is accessible from the another one, I set a different cookie name for each application but it still no change.

First Application

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(option =>
        {
            option.Cookie.Name = "FirstApp_CookieName";
            option.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            option.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            option.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            option.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;
        });
```

Second Application

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(option =>
            {
                option.Cookie.Name = "SecondApp_CookieName";
                option.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                option.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                option.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                option.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;

            });
```

Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to prevent a same-domain and https site to access your browser's cookie .The first thing is that it's better to avoid to include sensitive data in cookies .If you need to store them in cookie , encrypt the data with your own method . Another choice is saving the data on server side ,but add an identify(for example , Guid) in cookie to link the real data on server  .

Comment: It doesn't answer my question, I need to prevent both apps from accessing the other app's cookies.

Comment: @mhdsh , ok , i misunderstand your issue , see updated reply .

Answer (score 0):

Another option I would suggest for you is to change your authentication to `JWT Authentication`. Since `cookie authentication` sends the application cookie everytime it makes a request whether the request requires authentication or not, `JWT authentication` doesn't. Also if you return a `JWT token` for a specific user even though there are many applications in the same domain, they cannot be able to login to the other domain using a token which was not generated from the domain as you will configure each authentication mechanism only for that application.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set different domain\subdomain name for each cookie , that will resolve issue

Please add following to code httpCookie.Domain  = ""

[SAMISITE](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/)